# jQuery post dosen't return data

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to make a post with jquery like this:

```
function login(){
    var cor = $('#correo').val();
    var con = $('#contra').val();

    var posting = $.post("LogIn.php", {correo:cor, contra:con});

    posting.done(function(data){
        alert(data);
    },"json");
}
```

The PHP that I call just compares the data that I send and returns whether or not it is okay.

The problem is that my post doesn't return the data, it just does nothing.
But if with the PHP I try to insert into a database, it works but never performs the `echo`s from the PHP.
Could someone tell how can I fix it, or explain to me how it works?

Comment: What's that second "json" argument to `posting.done()` supposed to be for? That's not a valid argument: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

Comment: Tell me what u see in console: `$.post("LogIn.php", {correo:cor, contra:con}).done(function(r){console.log(r)});`

Comment: Sounds like you might have a problem in your PHP.  You should include that code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this type of posting is valid, but this is what I would do:

```
function login(){
    var cor = $('#correo').val();
    var con = $('#contra').val();
    $.post("LogIn.php", {correo:cor, contra:con}, function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

The jquery `$.post` has a success basically build in.  Just do all of the stuff you want to do on success in the function of the post.

I could be wrong, what with the JSON information you need back.

Comment: I try this kind of post before but with the same problem that dosent return me back the datas. I readed that I need callback the function because the post dosent attin the function

Comment: @leonfelipecorderopalacios Have you made sure the LogIn.php is in the correct location? When it reads from there, it's assuming the login.php is in the same folder as your html page

Comment: yes I´m sure, and when I make a insert or update in the php to the database its works but never return the datas

Comment: @leonfelipecorderopalacios,  can you post your php code? We'll have to verify what is being done there.